# If I have a number $N$, what operation can I use to make a number $X^N$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I'm trying to create a method to a way to take a number and make it a part of another “family” of numbers. For example, given a number $X$, to make it a part of the family of even numbers, just multiply it by 2. Basically, I just want to take a number $N$, and make it into $X^N$.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to do. You want to write $N$ as $X^N$? Then take $X=\sqrt[N]{N}$. But there have to be some restrictions to $X$ and $N$.

Comment: That’s what I was asking for, thank you, but what kind of restrictions?

Comment: For instance if N=-2, you would have $\sqrt[-2]{-2}$ which can not be solved in $\mathbb{R}$